# AES encrypt in python decrypt in php

Tags: python, php, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am asking this because I don't really know php but must to somehow manage with.
I have encrypted data in python and need to decrypt in php (serversite).
**python encryption:**

```
import hashlib
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode, urlsafe_b64encode, urlsafe_b64decode
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

text = "secret"
secret_key = 'This is my secret key'
secret_iv = 'This is my secret iv'

key = hashlib.sha256(secret_key.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()[:32].encode("utf-8")
iv = hashlib.sha256(secret_iv.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()[:16].encode("utf-8")

_pad = lambda s: s + (AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size) * chr(AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)

txt = _pad(text)

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
output = urlsafe_b64encode(cipher.encrypt(str.encode(txt))).rstrip(b'=')
```

this gives 'rtVabOaDdf528T63xOhhww' output, which is correctly AES encrypted.

**and php** which encrypts and decrypts in other way:

```
<?php

$string="secret";
class CryptService{
    private static $encryptMethod = 'AES-256-CBC';
    private $key;
    private $iv;

    public function __construct(){
       echo  '<br>: '.$this->key = substr(hash('sha256', 'This is my secret key'), 0, 32);
       echo  '<br>: '.$this->iv = substr(hash('sha256', 'This is my secret iv'), 0, 16).'<br>';
    }

    public function decrypt($string){
    // $string = strtr($data, '-_', '+/');

        $string = base64_decode($string);
        return openssl_decrypt($string, self::$encryptMethod, $this->key, 0, $this->iv);
    }

    public function encrypt($string){
        $output = openssl_encrypt($string, self::$encryptMethod, $this->key, 0, $this->iv);
        $output = base64_encode($output);
        return $output;
    }
}

$a = new CryptService;
echo $ok=$a->encrypt('secret');
echo "\n";
echo 'TEST: '.$a->decrypt($string);
echo 'BACK ok: '.$a->decrypt($ok);
echo "\n\n";
```

There is some issue with openssl_decrypt() function because of "iv". Can someone help me figure this out...

Comment: with your current code, you should get warning about IV being too long (passed is 20 bytes and excepted is 16). If you do not get this error message try to enable it by putting `error_reporting(-1);` in the first line of your script

Comment: Thanks EdvinasPocius, Martin Toms already helped me with this, but there is another issue.. I can't decrypt what I encrypted in python, basically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning additional 4 characters `<br>` to your $this->iv. This will fix it:

```
echo '<br>: ' . ($this->iv = substr(hash('sha256', 'This is my secret iv'), 0, 16)) . '<br>';
```

Basically, your `. '<br>'` is concatenating the `<br>` to your `substr()`. I added `()` around the variable value assignment. Now it works

```
cnRWYWJPYURkZjUyOFQ2M3hPaGh3dz09 TEST: BACK ok: secret
```

I am not an expert on encryption, but... I think there's something in your code that doesn't quite belong in there. When I remove these two lines:

```
$string = base64_decode($string);
$output = base64_encode($output);
```

I get this output:

```
rtVabOaDdf528T63xOhhww==
```

[image]

Which, after a `rtrim($ok, '=');`, would give you

```
rtVabOaDdf528T63xOhhww
```